# Checking if optional property has values

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following interface:

```
export interface Development {
  id: number;
  type: string;
  value: string;
  formContent?: contentInterface;
}
```

and `contentInterface` is an interface with the following:

```
 export interface contentInterface {
   development: string;
   name: string;
   comment: string;
 }
```

Now when I do the following :

```
  // tring to check if the next sectorForm[i] has formcontent values assigned
  // if values are available in formcontent add that to a form.

 if (typeof this.sectorForm[i + 1].formContent !== 'undefined') {  
  this.DevelopmentForm.setValue(this.sectorForm[i + 1].formContent);
 }
```

`sectorForm` is declared as follows : `sectorForm: Development[]`

the above code results to the following error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'formContent' of undefined` in the last index

Comment: This is *nothing to do with the optional property*, the whole object is undefined. Given that you're adding one you're probably past the end of the array, but we'd need a [mcve] to tell. And don't put that back in the post again.

Comment: Look at the error message, "Cannot read property '**formContent**' of **undefined**". That means that you are trying to access a `formContent` property from something that is undefined. That means `this.sectorForm[i + 1]` is returning undefined... perhaps you should ensure that you're either indexing the correct item in that array or ensure that an object actually exists at that index.

Comment: @Silva Since your issue is resolved you should mark one of the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

avoid issue with index do like this ,make use of `forEach`

```
 this.sectorForm.forEach(form => {
   //rest code 
    if (form.formContent)  { 

    }
   });
```

---

just do this

```
if (this.sectorForm[i + 1] && 
       this.sectorForm[i + 1].formContent)
```

Note : 
just in case if you are looking for property exists on object or not make use of `hasOwnProperty('property1')`

it will check null or undefined etc.

Comment: You have apparently not read the error message in the question; this will not help.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - it cannot read property that means its null not defined

Comment: Yes, but you need to think about *what* is undefined.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - got you updated my answer ... thanks for pointing it out

Comment: i made it optional because i have a second component, where i insert data based on the selected value and type. decided to combine everything because i thought its going to be easy when doing http posting.

Answer (score 0):

The item in the array may be null you should check for that first:

```
if (this.sectorForm[i + 1] && typeof this.sectorForm[i + 1].formContent !== 'undefined') {  
  this.DevelopmentForm.setValue(this.sectorForm[i + 1].formContent);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Works Perfect